# Azure Bicep contains for loop: For-expressions are not supported in this context

Tags: azure-bicep

I would like to provide backward compatibility with an existing set of parameters.json files, so that if the property `inboundSecurityRules` doesn't exist, then we just use an empty array that can be unioned together with other Security rules, and passed to the `nsg` resource.

```
param p_subnet object;

var inboundSecurityRules = contains(p_subnet, 'inboundSecurityRules') ? [for rule in p_subnet.inboundSecurityRules: {
  name         : rule.name
  properties   : union(
    rule.properties,
    { destinationAddressPrefix: p_subnet.addressPrefix }
  )
}] : []
```

Bicep error:

`For-expressions are not supported in this context. For-expressions may be used as values of resource, module, variable, and output declarations, or values of resource and module properties.`

Does anyone know how can this functionality could be achieved with this limitation?

Cheers

Comment: what is p_subnet ? just a subnet resource, variable, param ?

Comment: Sorry I should have made that clear. It's an object param. I've updated the code snippet to include that.

Answer (score 2):

ARM doesn't allow looping constructs within an `if()` function expression (which is what a Bicep ternary gets compiled down to), but you can nest the ternary within the `for` expression (instead of nesting the `for` expression within the ternary) to get around this limitation:

```
param p_subnet object

var inboundSecurityRules = [for rule in (contains(p_subnet, 'inboundSecurityRules') ? p_subnet.inboundSecurityRules : []): {
  name         : rule.name
  properties   : union(
    rule.properties,
    { destinationAddressPrefix: p_subnet.addressPrefix }
  )
}]
```